# Memory use by webview

Tags: android, android-listview, memory-leaks, webview

I am using a `WebView` as a `ListItem` in a `ListView`.

I am using `ViewHolder` pattern as well.

The `WebView`is getting the data from an HTML resource.

After each scroll of the list view, the heap memory consumption by a particular `WebView` goes up.

Why is this happening and can this be reduced?

Comment: Use the Debug class to trace. Then use Traceview to analyze the trace. This is the closest you can get to know of the bottlenecks, also I would suggest using tools to analyze your view hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

If you use an adpter to populate your ListView,(if not try to write your own) it's worth doing since then you can control the creating of the ListView items from getView delegate.